# set session on cxf

Tags: java, session, cxf

I'm trying to set Session on CXF Webservice. The code is:

>

```
 package com.esb.cxf;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.ConsumeMime;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.ProduceMime;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Path("/")
@ProduceMime({ "application/json" })
public class SSO {

    private String urlSCS = "http://localhost:8080/SCS/";



    @GET
    @Path("/session/")
    @ConsumeMime({ "application/json" })
    @ProduceMime({ "test/plain" })
    public String pool(HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60);
        session.setAttribute("uidsso", "test");

        String sessionSCS = "";

        try {

            sessionSCS = session.getAttribute("uidsso").toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        String req = request.getLocalName();


        return req;

    }
```

The problem is, that when i getting on the websrvice by browswer :

> http://localhost:8181/cxf/sso/session

my code doesn't set any session

What is wrong?

Comment: remove the empty catch block `catch (Exception e) {    }` and maybe someone will help you

Comment: general comment - productMime = text/plain; I donot think you can gain access to session while using web service of any kind because they are ideally stateless, although restful web service are servlets.

Comment: @artbristol - try/catch is for get session, but i don't see the session im my firefox - so the session is not set

Comment: your empty catch block is suppressing the explanation of what's happening

Comment: @artbristol - i deleted the try/catch code and nothing happend. I'm not sure if i can set session/cookie by cxf webservice. maybe you know how to redirect from webservice to another website ?

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Can you sniff the HTTP traffic to see if the `Set-Cookie` header is being set?

Comment: You are likely to get better help at the Apache CXF user list.